# Время жизни кука Django

Tags: python, django

Привет. Как в Django установить время жизни COOKIE файла?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Определите константу `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE` (время актуальности cookie в секундах), подробнее смотрите в [документации](https://djbook.ru/rel1.8/ref/settings.html#std:setting-SESSION_COOKIE_AGE). По умолчанию оно равно 2 неделям. После окончания времени файл не удалится сразу же, но станет неактуальным.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Не могли бы вы еще подсказать как правильно проверить есть ли кук со значением в реквесте уже?

Comment: Я, к сожалению, не знаю, как правильно это проверить. Задайте новый вопрос, в котором подробно опишите проблему, или воспользуйтесь [поиском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=cookie+%5Bdjango%5D)