# Django. Время жизни cookie и session

Tags: python, django

Казалось бы простая задача, но что-то упускаю. Пытаюсь передать во `view` `GET-параметр` и записать в `cookie` с временем жизни до того, как пользователь покинет сайт (закроет вкладку или браузер). `Cookie` записывается и читается отлично, вот только слишком живучая оказывается.

```
def home(request):
    ''' Вместо не относящегося к вопросу кода... '''
    referral = request.GET.get('ref', '')
    if referral:
        response = render_to_response('index.html', args)
        response.set_cookie('referral', referral)
        return response
    else:
        return render_to_response('index.html', args)
```

На сколько я понимаю, то `Django` устанавливает время жизни этой `cookie` равное время жизни сессии. Но параметры `max_age` и `expires` по умолчанию должны быть `None` и если верить документации это означает, что время жизни до закрытия браузера. Так же пробовал указать их явно, результат тот же.
Так как позже надо будет сделать время жизни сессии так же до закрытия, пробовал в `settings.py` добавить `SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE` равное `True`, но что сессия, что установленная мной `cookie` продолжают жить и авторизация не слетает, а вроде должна. Собственно вопрос... что не так?

Comment: Время жизни кука [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/648762/%D0%92%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0-django), время жизни сессии [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14830669/how-to-expire-django-session-in-5minutes)

Comment: В ваших примерах, в обоих случаях надо указывать время в секундах и 0 не подойдёт, а мне надо до закрытия сделать.